# What parameters are required to use x264 via ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat, libx264

i have an AVI file, i have decoded it into Raw form first, now i want to encode it in .h264 format. I am using libavcodec.dll and libavformat.dll.
The point is when i try to open the codec from avcodec_open(AVCodecContext,AVCodec)
It doesnot open. Am i missing some parameters that i need to specify for execution of this method for the lib x264?
Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways to encode AVI file to H.264 using x264:

1, Compile and install ffmpeg, with `--enable-shared`, then compile and install x264. You'll see lavf: yes when configuring. Then do the converting using x264 cli or something else(such as DirectX264).

2, Compile and install x264, with `--enable-shared`, then compile and install ffmpeg with `--enable-libx264`. Then you will be able to convert using ffmpeg cli or something else(such as WinFF).

And btw .h264 is not a sufficient suffix, please use ".mkv", ".mp4" or something instead.

Comment: Agreed, FFMpeg doesn't contain an H264 encoder, you have to install libx264 as well.

Comment: .h264 is for raw h.264 video where .mp4 and .mkv are container formats that allow multiple audio and video streams